# Set an option dependent on the filetype

Tags: vimrc

How to configure on the `.vimrc` file to use a particular set options for a particular filetype, but others for a different filetype?

For example, I want to enable expand tab (set tabs to be spaces) for Python files, but disable it for C++ files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I put this sort of thing in `$HOME/.vim/ftdetect/{FILETYPE}.vim`.  To accomplish what you want I would have the following files.

For python...

```
"$HOME/.vim/ftdetect/python.vim
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.py set noexpandtab
```

And for C++...

```
"$HOME/.vim/ftdetect/cpp.vim
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.cpp set expandtab
```

What these commands do is set the `expandtab` or `noexpandtab` options for a specific buffer which gets created for, or reads in, a file that matches one of the patterns `*.py` or `*.cpp`.

Comment: `ftdetect` is meant for detecting filetypes, use an `ftplugin` instead, there you don't need an `autocmd`, just use `setlocal` instead though.